# Можно ли в Python менять оператор сравнения в if через переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли переменной присвоить знаки < или > и использовать их в if. Если нет, то как это можно сделать?
Нужно примерно так:

```
a = "<"
b = 0 
c = 1
if c a b:
...
```

Comment: присвоить можно, но не знак, а символ. Использовать так, как вы хочете, нельзя.

Comment: Не думаю, что такое можно... Вы можете знак оставить тот же - `<`, но в зависимости от условий в `a` поменять местами значения переменных `b` и `c`, или сохранить результат их сравнения и инвертировать его. А зачем это нужно?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Плюсую модуль `operator`, очень удобная штука )

Comment: Честно говоря, слышу про такое в первые. А какая задача перед вами стоит ?
Так, как вы это делаете - нельзя, можно менять только операнды, но нельзя изменить оператор.

Comment: В питоне можно почти всё )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор нельзя записать в переменную. В данном случае вместо операторов можно использовать функции, которые выполняют соответствующие операции. Функции можно записывать в переменные.

Т.е., для примера

```
def is_less(a, b):
    return a < b

a = is_less
b = 0 
c = 1
if a(c, b):
    ...
```

Есть стандартный модуль [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) с функциями, соответствующими операторам. Оператору `<` соответствует функция `operator.lt`, `>` - `operator.gt`.

```
import operator

a = opertator.lt  # или operator.gt
b = 0
c = 1
if a(c, b):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Повторяя фразу, произнесённую на этом сайте скажу *"Если Вам это понадобилось, значит что-то Вы делаете неправильно"*
Да простит меня Ктулху за этот изврат:

```py
from operator import lt, eq, gt

op = {
    '>': gt,
    '<': lt,
    '==': eq
}
a = op.get("==", eq)
b = 1
c = 1
if a(b, c):
    print('ok')
```